# select from table using another select in the same query

Tags: php, mysqli

the mysql scenario:

table: `posts` => `postId`, `userId` `postContent`;
table: `friends` => `friendId`, `userA`, `userB`;

query:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE userId IN (SELECT * FROM friends WHERE userA = {$_SESSION['userId']} OR userB = {$_SESSION['userId']});
```

> `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given

what am i missing in the query?

Comment: echo the query first , you may get the error.identify it

Comment: replace * in second query with userid coloumn

Comment: Show how you use it in code. It's PHP error, not MySql. Also use prepared statement instead of putting variables direct in query - SQL Injection security issue

Comment: Second query should only return userid not all coloumns.

Comment: Please post the PHP code as well

Comment: Fix your query in SQL Editor first (HeidiSQL or SQLWorkbench) before fixing it in php.

Comment: `$queryGrabPosts = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE userId IN (SELECT userId FROM friends WHERE userA = {$_SESSION['userId']} OR userB = {$_SESSION['userId']})");

            
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryGrabPosts)) {
    echo $row['postContent'];
}`

Comment: What datatype are `userA` and `userB`?

Comment: `friends` columns are all ints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** :
With one subquerie

```
SELECT *
FROM posts 
WHERE userId IN (
    SELECT 

    CASE 
        WHEN userA = {$_SESSION['userId']} THEN userB
        ELSE userA
    END as user

    FROM friends WHERE userA = {$_SESSION['userId']} OR userB = {$_SESSION['userId']}
);
```

**OLD ANSWER :**

I search a better solution, but I think it work with two subqueries :

```
SELECT *
FROM posts 
WHERE userId IN (SELECT userB FROM friends WHERE userA = {$_SESSION['userId']}) OR userId IN (SELECT userA FROM friends WHERE userB = {$_SESSION['userId']});
```

But please, consider using PDO for improve security

Comment: i get the same result

Comment: Did you have corrected the mistake in my code (replace id by userId before the last select).
This SQL code run on my db.

Answer (score -1):

please try this

```
SELECT *
FROM statements 
WHERE userId IN (SELECT userId FROM friends WHERE userA = {$_SESSION['userId']} OR userB = {$_SESSION['userId']});
```

Comment: same result i get on the query